# Can't build our solution with MSBUILD, it can't find our .targets files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I've written some windows batch files to call msbuild for all of the VS solutions that our product consists of.

They all work except one SLN, in which to CSPROJ files are causing problems.

The projects all build in VS2008.

**PROJECT FOLDER LAYOUT**

```
\RootFolder
   \LinqToXsd
     -LinqToXsd.targets
     -Xml.Schema.Linq.dll
   \BL
     -BL.csproj
   \Config
     -Config.csproj
```

We have customized the CSPROJ files to pull in LinqToXsd:

Added this line to the first `PropertyGroup`:

```
<LinqToXsdBinDir Condition="'$(LinqToXsdBinDir)' == ''">$(SolutionDir)\..\LinqToXsd</LinqToXsdBinDir>
```

And this line after the `Import` for `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`

```
<Import Project="$(LinqToXsdBinDir)\LinqToXsd.targets" />
```

Command Line:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\msbuild.exe /m /target:Build /nologo /property:BuildInParallel=true;OutDir=E:\Projects\BuildMaster\trunk\built\ConfigTool\;Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal "*snip*\ConfigTool\ConfigTool.sln"
```

Problem is, we get this in the output:

```
*snip*\ConfigTool\ConfigTool.csproj(131,11): error MSB4019: The imported project "E:\LinqToXsd\LinqToXsd.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
ConfigTool.csproj : Solution file warning MSB4122: Scanning project dependencies for project "ConfigTool.csproj" failed. The imported project "E:\LinqToXsd\LinqToXsd.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  *snip*\ConfigTool\ConfigTool.csproj
*snip*\BL\BL.csproj(352,11): error MSB4019: The imported project "E:\LinqToXsd\LinqToXsd.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
..\BL\BL.csproj : Solution file warning MSB4122: Scanning project dependencies for project "..\BL\BL.csproj" failed. The imported project "E:\LinqToXsd\LinqToXsd.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  *snip*\BL\BL.csproj
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Xml.Schema.Linq". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

Yet I've got other projects that use those lines and work perfectly. Including ones that reference the same CSPROJ files (share BL).

I've tried deleting all the bin, obj, cache, suo and user files/folders, no difference.

Any msbuild experts out there that can help?

Thanks,

J1M.

**UPDATE1**

If I replace this line:

```
<LinqToXsdBinDir Condition="'$(LinqToXsdBinDir)' == ''">$(SolutionDir)..\LinqToXsd</LinqToXsdBinDir>
```

With this line:

```
<LinqToXsdBinDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\LinqToXsd</LinqToXsdBinDir>
```

In the ConfigTool and BL project files, I no longer get errors about LinqToXsd not being found when it compiles the BL, although it can't find the compiled BL dll.

**SOLUTION**

First off, SolutionDir is only defined by VS2008, not MSBUILD it seems.
You can pass it in on the command line but I chose to do the following:

```
<LinqToXsdBinDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\LinqToXsd</LinqToXsdBinDir>
```

`MSBuildProjectDirectory` is defined in both VS and MSBUILD.

Second, a different problem that caused the same symptoms (don't know why)

One of the projects (BL) referenced a subordinate (SL) and SL's GUID had changed.
This didn't matter in VS but MSBUILD *really* didn't like it.

Deleting and recreating the refs fixed the second solution.

I only found out about it during my random csproj hackings when suddenly MSBUILD started reporting an error about `project {guid} referencing project {guid} which is not available in the SLN file`

Thanks,

`J1M`

Comment: Have you in fact confirmed that "E:\LinqToXsd\LinqToXsd.targets" exists?  Is that where you expect it to be?

Comment: No, ah, sorry, I should probably add to the question the project layout. It's NOT supposed to be there.

Comment: OK, it now compiles. I shall update the original question with all the things I found wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSBuild does not define the `SolutionDir` property so you'll need to manually specify it:

```
msbuild.exe /p:SolutionDir=... other options
```

Comment: I've already tried replacing it with `MSBuildProjectDirectory`, which apparently should work. I'm going to try just putting full paths in to see whether this has anything to do with it not building the paths correctly

Comment: There were two problems both with the same symptoms. This solved one of them, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nuget works in a similar way. It places it's targets in a subfolder off the solution root. For each project that uses nuget it edits the .*proj file and adds the following `SolutionDir` property. If you provide a default value for `SolutionDir` in this manner you shouldn't have to pass it as a command line argument when you invoke msbuild:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- ... other properties -->
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

then just update your target like this:

```
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\LinqToXsd\LinqToXsd.targets" />
```

Comment: Not the answer, but I prefer than notation. Thanks, I'll use that instead.